# NLTK extracting terms of chunker parse tree

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

> **John Edward Grey** started **running** now that he knows he is **fat**
>
> **She** was **listening** to **smack that** by that **awful singer**

I want to extract interesting terms from a sentence. I currently use POS tagging to identify grammatical types of each entity. Then I update each token to a counter (with different weights for nouns, verbs and adjectives).

I now wish to use a chunker for this. I think the **leaf nodes of the parse tree holds all interesting words and phrases**. How do I extract the terms from a chunker output?

Comment: Chunkers don't produce parse trees. If by "chunker" you meant "parser", then the leaf nodes typically hold only the words, not multi-word phrases.

Comment: I chose the wrong terminology. But then I saw __"A chunk structure is a tree containing tokens and chunks"__ and stuff meaning its a "shallow tree structure". Whats the correct name of the component that extracts phrased entities?

Comment: That's a chunker. It produces a very simple structure of two levels, tokens and chunks; calling that a tree is mathematically correct, but has no practical value. If you do regard it as a tree, then the leaves are not the interesting elements, but the higher-level elements.

Comment: You want the verb "running", but not "listening"?

Comment: What makes a word "interesting" for your purposes?

Answer (score 4):

In linguistics, the "interesting words" are call `open class words`.
And the task you are referring to is not really a chunking/parsing task. You are looking for some sort of tagger/annotator/labeller to tag each word to see whether it is "interesting" or not.

**Sequence Labelling**

If you approach your task as a sequence labelling task, then the sentence `John Edward Grey started running now that he knows he is fat` will be tagged as such:

```
[('John','B'),('Edward','I'),('Grey','I'),('started','O'),('running','B'),
('now','O'),('that','O'),('he','O'),('knows','O'),('he','O'),
('is','O'),('fat','B')]
```

- So anything tagged with `B` means a beginning of your "interesting" chunk and
- the subsequent word tagged with `O` will be the end of the "interesting" chunk or
- it can also end up with a subsequent `B` to label the end of the previous "interesting" chunk and the start of a new "interesting" chunk.

**What is interesting or not?**

Actually what is interesting or not depends on what is your ultimate aim of the task, to me, I would have said that `started running` is an "interesting" chunk because it started modifies the infinitive meaning or `running` to give it a `begin action` modality.

**Closed class vs Open class words**

If you have in mind what are the non-interesting words, then i suggest you build a dictionary of that and then run a sequence labeling script to detect those not in the dictionary of close class words.

**Machine learning Approach**

Another approach is to perform machine learning classification task where you have already pre-annotated a sample data of what is interesting and what is not. Then you identify some classification features and run the classification to automatically tag the data with `B`,`I`,`O` tags.